# Inject Adapter to Fragment using Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dagger-2

I have followed Android Architecture Blueprints Dagger2 for dependency injection : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger

Now I want to inject Adapter to my Fragment class :

```
@ActivityScoped
class MainFragment @Inject
constructor(): DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var adapter : ArtistAdapter 
}
```

And I have following in the module class :

```
@Module
abstract class MainModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun mainFragment(): MainFragment

    @Module
    companion object {
        @Provides
        @ActivityScoped
        @JvmStatic internal fun provideArtistAdapter() = ArtistAdapter()
    }
}
```

But for some reason it fails to display data in RecyclerView. When I don't use injection and simply use `val adapter = ArtistAdapter()`, it works.

What am I missing in injection using Dagger2?

Addenda :

`mainFragment` is implementing a callback as a click listener:

```
interface ArtistClickCallback {
    fun onClick(artist: LastFmArtist, poster : ImageView)
}
```

And :

```
class MainFragment : DaggerFragment(), ArtistClickCallback
```

And here is fragment module :

```
@Module
class MainFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideArtistAdapter(mainFragment: MainFragment) = ArtistAdapter(mainFragment)

}
```

But I get following exception when I remove @Inject from Fragment constructor:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.sample.android.lastfm.ui.main.MainFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.sample.android.lastfm.LastFmApp> {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.sample.android.lastfm.ui.main.MainModule_MainFragment$app_debug.MainFragmentSubcomponent
      com.sample.android.lastfm.ui.main.MainFragment is injected at
          com.sample.android.lastfm.ui.main.MainActivity.mainFragment
      com.sample.android.lastfm.ui.main.MainActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.sample.android.lastfm.di.AppComponent → com.sample.android.lastfm.di.ActivityBindingModule_MainActivity$app_debug.MainActivitySubcomponent]
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use @Inject annotation in Fragment's constructor. 2. You should use same scope - FragmentScoped in MainFragment and companion object. 3. In fragment's onAttach or onCreate you should call DaggerFragmentComponent.inject(fragment).

Comment: Look at google sample where they have used @inject annotation in constructor : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to inject the adapter? Is there any practical benefit to it? I've seen it before but I'm not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, there is no particular reason. I just asked for the purpose of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @Inject from Fragment constructor and provide the adapter to the fragment or use an inject constructor in your adapter

```
@Module
abstract class MainModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyAwesomeFragmentModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainFragment(): MainFragment

}
```

-

```
@Module
class MyAwesomeFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideArtistAdapter() = ArtistAdapter()

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ismael Di Vita. I am receiving an exception when I build. Please look at the `addenda` section in my question.